# Python os.chdir is modifying the passed directory name

Tags: python, python-2.7, directory, chdir

I am trying to change the current working directory in python using os.chdir. I have the following code:

```
import os

os.chdir("C:\Users\Josh\Desktop\20130216")
```

However, when I run it, it seems to change the directory, as it comes out with the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Josh\Desktop\LapseBot 1.0\LapseBot.py", line 3, in <module>
os.chdir("C:\Users\Josh\Desktop\20130216")
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
  'C:\\Users\\Josh\\Desktop\x8130216'
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Try to add another backlash before "2013"

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Python is interpreting the `\2013` part of the path as the *escape sequence* `\201`, which maps to the character `\x81`, which is ü (and of course, `C:\Users\Josh\Desktopü30216` doesn't exist).

Use a raw string, to make sure that Python doesn't try to interpret anything following a `\` as an escape sequence.

```
os.chdir(r"C:\Users\Josh\Desktop\20130216")
```

Comment: Or use forward slashes, or double the backslashes.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yep, good point. Python can correctly understand paths like `C:/Users/Josh/...` on Windows.

Comment: what does the "r" do??

Comment: @Nabin It's how you define a raw string, i.e. a string without any escape sequences

Answer (score 4):

You could also use `os.path.join` ([documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)).
Example:

```
os.chdir(os.path.join('C:\Users\Josh\Desktop', '20130216'))
```

This is more elegant + it's compatible with different operating systems.

Answer (score 3):

This should work -

```
os.chdir("C:\Users\Josh\Desktop\\20130216")
```

Comment: why do you need the second backslash?

Comment: @Stephan Because "\201" is a character. We need to escape the backslash to tell python that you didn't mean that but it's just another backslash (in fact path separator here)

Answer (score 0):

There are two to use `os.chdir()`:

1. If you are using raw string than use single backslash `\`:

   os.chdir(r"C:\Users\Josh\Desktop\20130216")

**or**

2. If you are not using raw string than use double backslash `\\`

   os.chdir("C:\Users\Josh\Desktop\20130216")

Answer (score -1):

I have faced the same problem but you have to try:

```
os.chdir(c:\\user\\Josh\\Desktop)
```

Use `\\` so maybe you should get your solution.